# Returning a String and Understanding Redirection and Output

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I'm trying to figure out how redirects could be used to selectively output a string from a bash function which needs to print multiple lines to the terminal. I found an answer on this [question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function). The code below works. But I don't understand how or why.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1

returnString()
{
    exec 4>&1 >&3
    local s=$1
    s=${s:="some default string"}
    echo "writing to stdout"
    echo "writing to stderr" >&2
    exec >&4-
    echo "$s"
}

my_string=$(returnString "$*")
echo "my_string:  [$my_string]"
```

I understand that fd3 is redirected to `stdout` at the beginning. Then fd4 is as well, and 1 is pointed at 3, which basically points it back at itself. But how does this effect what is printed to the terminal, and why doesn't that output show up in `$my_string`, but the last one after getting rid of fd4 does?

I don't understand what fd4 has to do with anything, since nothing is explicitly sent to fd4.

Comment: You need to understand about shell pipes/redirection beyond `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. Here is my favorite tutorial, if you wanna call it that. [http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)

Comment: Wow! That was helpful, but also a bit overwhelming. It seems to assume some understanding of how pipes are set up already though, which I don't have.

Comment: dealing with file descriptors is no small thing to balk at. I never use them, never needed to. Good way to shoot yourself at foot in my opinion. I stick to K.I.S.S. principle : **K**eep **I**t **S**tupidly **S**imple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are showing above is one that is general purpose and covers a lot of cases.  Unless you know you have an issue, you may want to adopt a YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) posture and just redirect your selected lines to /dev/tty.

If you want to avoid that, then you need to understand the file descriptor (fd) juggling that is going on.

The `3>&1` is copying the calling context's stdout to a "holding cell" so that the function can output to whatever the calling context's stdout is. In this case, it is /dev/tty. Remember, the function will be called with stdout belonging to a subshell for the ${} substitution.

The `exec 4>&1` creates a copy of fd1, which is the stdout of the function. fd4 is being used as a holding cell for the stdout the function starts with. The `>&3` is setting the function/subshell's stdout to the caller's stdout.  Thus, all output will go to the caller's stdoout.  UNTIL, the end where the `>&4-` moves the saved stdout back to where it started, allowing the last `echo "$s"` to be in the function(and subshell)'s stdout.

Whew!

The `>&3` and `>&4-` could also be written more clearly as `1>&3` and `1>&4-`.

The `bash` manual section on REDIRECTION, explains all the gory & nomenclature.  I was pleased and surprised to see that it is actually possible to use {name} forms to change the numbers to words.

"Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of  the  form {varname}.  In this case, for each redirection operator except >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to varname.  If >&- or  <&-  is  preceded by {varname}, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close."

I didn't test this, but it suggests that you could code this as:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec {caller_stdio}>&1

returnString() {
  exec {func_stdio}>&1 1>&{caller_stdio}
  local s=$1
  s=${s:="some default string"}
  echo "writing to stdout"
  echo "writing to stderr" >&2
  exec 1>&{func_stdio}-
  echo "$s"
}

my_string=$(returnString "$*")
echo "my_string:  [$my_string]"
```

Comment: Very helpful explanation, and very interesting bit about the names. Could that possibly collide with another named variable though?

Comment: My guess is that it `bash` probably uses the same symbol table for all its symbols.  So you would need to choose your names to avoid collision just as you would in a shell script.

Comment: I cannot comment on StackExchange questions (yet), but to your question in the other answer about what the `exec >&4-` does, is that it _moves_ the fd from 4 to 1.  See the "Moving File Descriptors" subsection in the REDIRECTION section of the `bash` manual for full details.  That entire section would be worth a read if you want to get a good handle on this feature.  It is very terse, but quite clear.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've been reading [this manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC40). It's making much more sense after reading these answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
exec 3>&1
```

fd 3 is now a [dup](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) of fd 1 (in your example, your terminal). As the man page says, it means that fd 1 and fd 3 can be used interchangeably to refer to the same file or device.

The major use of duping in the shell is to save a copy of an fd so that it can be restored later.

```
my_string=$(returnString "$*")
```

In order for bash to get the stdout output from the evaluation of `returnString "$*"`, it creates a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pipe) and forks, and the child calls [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) to *move* the write end of the pipe (in this example, it's fd 5, but that can vary) to fd 1.

```
exec 4>&1 >&3
```

Redirections are evaluated left to right. fd 4 is set to be a dup of the pipe end. Then, fd 1 is set to be a dup of the fd that refers to your terminal.

```
echo "writing to stdout"
```

echoes to fd 1, your terminal.

```
exec >&4-
```

This moves (that is, does a dup2) of fd 4 to fd 1. fd 1 is now the pipe end.

```
echo "$s"
```

echoes to the pipe end. Eventually, this is read by the parent shell from the other end of the pipe and used as the result of `$(returnString "$*")`

Comment: Very helpful! Can you clarify this statement though:  
  `In order for bash to get the stdout output from the evaluation of returnString "$*", it creates a pipe and forks, and the child calls dup2 to move the write end of the pipe (in this example, it's fd 5, but that can vary) to fd 1.`

How do you know it would be fd5 in this case?

Comment: The `open`, `dup`, and `pipe` system calls used by the shell always use the lowest available fd. Your script started with fd's 0, 1, and 2 open (as usual). then `exec 3`  allocated fd 3, then the `pipe` allocated 4 and 5, with 5 subsequently closed by the parent and moved to 1 by the child just before `returnString` was called. I saw all this by using `strace -f` on your shell script.

Comment: Thank you, also very helpful! I'm trying to apply this to a larger script and running into problems, so being able to watch what is happening with the fd's would be helpful.

Comment: in the step where fd 4 is duped to fd 1 (`exec >&4-`), any idea why the trailing `-` exists? I was thinking `exec >&4` should suffice

Comment: Because we don't need fd4 anymore so we're cleaning up by closing it?

Comment: Yes, `>&4-` does a `dup2`, moving 4 to 1 and closing 4.