# Redirection Error in Function

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I'm trying to figure out why the code below doesn't work, and gives me an error `Bad file descriptor`. It is sort of a follow-up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270735/returning-a-string-and-understanding-redirection-and-output) as applies to the script I'm currently working on.

Early on in the caller, `exec 3>&1` is run, and nothing later explicitly changes it before the (generalized) function below is called like so:

```
exec 3>&1
...
string=$(GetString)
```

GetString looks like this:

```
GetString()
{
    4>&1 1>&3    #save pipe end and change output back to caller's
    controlvar=0

    while ((controlvar != 1))
    do    
        printf "some stuff for the interactive user\n"
        read -p "my prompt" variable
        if ValidationFunction $variable; controlvar=1;fi    #tests for valid input
    done
    exec 1>&4-    #change output back to pipe end
    echo $variable
}
```

I'm getting the `Bad file descriptor` error on the second to last line.

What's going on here? Note that I'm also not doing anything explicitly with fd/4 elsewhere in the script.

Comment: The `exec 1>4-` is incorrect, use `exec 1>&4-`.

Comment: I'm almost sure you don't need all of that... especially `exec`'s... Can't you just pass file names? E.g. `<command> << "$infile" >> "$outfile"`, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryZebra. That was just a typo. I had to copy the code and output by hand as it's running in a VM with no network access at the moment.

Comment: @BryKKan A `exec 1>4&-` is still wrong, And I am leaning toward recommending the use of the simpler `exec 4>&-` to close file descriptor `4` but only after `exec 1>&0` to recover stdout.

Comment: @BinaryZebra please see the linked thread where this is exactly the syntax we used. If you still think it's wrong, feel free to post an answer explaining why. I'd love to hear.

Comment: What is written [in this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270745/79743) is `1>&4-`, well in fact, the equivalent `>&4-`. What you have written here is `>4&-`. If you fail to see the difference, well, nothing else to say.

Comment: And, you are missing an exec in the `4>&1 1>&3` line.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Holy crap! First one is just another typo. Can't believe I didn't fix it correctly the first time. The second is 100% the problem, and I now feel like an idiot. Perhaps make that an answer and I'll select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your question.

The line

```
4>&1 1>&3
```

Is missing an exec:

```
exec 4>&1 1>&3
```

And the line:

```
exec 1>4&-
```

Should read

```
exec 1>&4-
```

---

A simplified script should look as this:

```
GetString()
{
    exec 4>&1 1>&3    #save pipe end and change output back to caller's
    printf "some stuff for the interactive user\n"
    sleep 3    
    exec >&4-         #change output back to pipe end
    echo "test value"
}

exec 3>&1
string=$(GetString)
echo "final value <$string>"
```

This script makes sense.

Please edit the question to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the repeated typo. The edited code is now exactly as it was on my terminal, and adding the foolishly forgotten exec fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.